# Doesn't do anything after select Install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I launch the HD and it recognize. But when i select lenguage and press the opcion install Ubutu don't do anything. It just reboot my PC.

It's another way to install?

thanks for helping me.

Best regards.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, please describe details e.g. what version of OS 19.10 or 16.04/18.04 LTS into what kind of machine 32/64 bit, total memory, the hard drive is empty or occupied with another OS likewise Windows. Then answerer can be easy to detect what is wrong with your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you made a mistake when you tried to install Ubuntu. Your description is too short and vague to be sure, but it looks like you copied the *installer* onto your hard drive. That won't work, as you have discovered.

Check out http://tutorials.ubuntu.com to learn how to use the installer properly, and how to correctly and safely install Ubuntu.

Comment: I create the booteable using the guide i read on ubuntu page. i'm going to try install using CD. I get to the list of options that appears when recognize ubuntu ISO from USB, but when i select option "install Ubuntu" my pc just reboot and repeat the process.

Don't do the installation. My pc fits the requirements, so i don't know what is happend.

Comment: CDs are too small for most Ubuntu Desktop images.